# How to test the same column value for all tables in a JOIN clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following example query;

```
SELECT S.Column1, S.Column2
FROM TableS as S
LEFT JOIN TableP as P ON S.PID = P.ID
LEFT JOIN TableI as I ON P.IID = I.ID
WHERE I.Identifier = 'StringIdentifier'
      AND I.Relevant = 1
      AND P.Relevant = 1
      AND S.Relevant = 1
```

Is there any way to simplify the last 3 lines to only one, to check the `Relevant` column from all the tables in one go?

Obviously replacing the last 3 lines with just a line `AND Relevant = 1` will not work because it gives the error:

> Ambiguous column name 'Relevant'.

Edit: The datatype of `Relevant` column is bit.

Comment: If the values of Relevant in all 3 columns are positive integers you could do `I.Relevant * P.Relevant * S.Relevant = 1`

Comment: @forpas, datatype of `Relevant` is bit

Comment: Your LEFT JOIN's execute as regular inner joins. Move the WHERE clause's I and P conditions to the ON clauses respectively, and you'll get true LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an index on that column, then this is the way to go.

If you do not, and just want it to look fancy or nice you can do something like:

```
AND I.Relevant * P.Relevant * S.Relevant = 1 -- assuming they are numeric
AND I.Relevant & P.Relevant & S.Relevant = 1 -- assuming bit
```

If not numeric or bit (text) then you need to cast to numeric and it will again not look that nice.

Also, I would suggest losing the left (from join) as in many cases it will be faster and on this code it does not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Your `WHERE` condition are turning the `JOIN`s into inner joins, so you should express the joins correctly:

```
SELECT S.Column1, S.Column2
FROM TableS S JOIN
     TableP P
     ON S.PID = P.ID JOIN
     TableI I
     ON P.IID = I.ID AND I.Identifier = 'StringIdentifier'
WHERE I.Relevant = 1 AND
      P.Relevant = 1 AND
      S.Relevant = 1;
```

Assuming `Relevant` takes on only the values of 0/1, you *could* use a lateral join:

```
SELECT S.Column1, S.Column2
FROM TableS S JOIN
     TableP P
     ON S.PID = P.ID JOIN
     TableI I
     ON P.IID = I.ID AND
        I.Identifier = 'StringIdentifier' CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT MIN(v.Relevant) as min_relevant
      FROM (VALUES (I.Relevant), (P.Relevant), (S.Relevant)
           ) v(Relevant)
     ) v
WHERE v.min_relevant = 1;
```

This isn't really helpful for 3 comparisons.  But if you had a dozen, it would be useful.

Comment: but the `IN` is not the same. It's using `OR`s instead of `AND`s

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that you have to repeat the `1` and not the length of the expression you could use `ALL`.

```
SELECT S.Column1, S.Column2
FROM TableS as S
LEFT JOIN TableP as P ON S.PID = P.ID
LEFT JOIN TableI as I ON P.IID = I.ID
WHERE I.Identifier = 'StringIdentifier'
      AND 1 = ALL(SELECT I.Relevant
                  UNION
                  SELECT P.Relevant
                  UNION
                  SELECT S.Relevant)
```

Comment: While this is a possible solution, would this perform better, the same, or worse than the original query? Just curious as I wouldn't want to change to a query that performs worse just for the sake of saving myself from typing "1" 3 times.

Comment: @RyanWilson: Good point! I'd guess the version in the OP can use indexes whereas my `ALL` version cannot. So it'll perform worse I assume. From the performance perspective the OP version should be the best possible. Unless the optimizer is smart enough to gain that original form from the others. But I have doubts about that.

Comment: Couldn't you make this a `View` and then index your `View`? Just a thought since you brought up the point about indexing.

Comment: @RyanWilson: What part would you want to turn in a view?

Comment: everything until you reach the `WHERE` clause and you can then index the `Relevant` columns for each table, just was kind of a question/suggestion as I have read about Indexed Views but have not had any experience using them.

Answer (score 0):

That query is wrong because there are 2 left join but in the where there are conditions over those tables
I propose:

```
SELECT S.Column1, S.Column2
FROM TableS as S
    LEFT JOIN TableP as P ON S.PID = P.ID AND P.Relevant = 1
    LEFT JOIN TableI as I ON P.IID = I.ID AND I.Identifier = 'StringIdentifier' AND I.Relevant = 1
WHERE S.Relevant = 1
```

It is better a correct query than a simplified query

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that Relevant is a bool you could do

`...
and I.Relevant and P.Relevant and S.Relevant`

Comment: I think the OP still needs all three to be equal to 1. I didn't down-vote, but I'm guessing that is why others are.

Comment: Will this work with `BIT` columns? I've never tried it. The OP just specified in their comments that they are `BIT` columns

Comment: This gives the error `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'.`

Comment: @Lamak Thank you for answering my question and to you ruohola for the error message.

Comment: if they are bit you could try `... and I.Relevant+P.Relevant+S.Relevant=3`

Comment: @Radacina they are bit, like I specified in my edit to the question.

Comment: @Radacina that gives the error `The data types bit and bit are incompatible in the add operator.`

Comment: @ruhola please check the second solution in Dumitrescu Bogdan's answer